# Minimum number of operations to make every element of an array consecutive if ordered

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given an array, return the minimum number of operations required to make all the elements of the array continuous. In one operation, any element of the array can be replaced with any integer. For example =>

```
arr = [6, 4, 1, 7, 10]
```

the output should be continuousElementsArray(arr) = 2. By converting 1 -> 5 and 10 -> 8 Final array is

```
arr = [6, 4, 5, 7, 8]
```

Continuous mean that number should be consecutive like {1,2,3} or {2,3,1}. Here order doesn't matter. And every number should be unique (No repetition is allowed).

Comment: Where have you got so far?

Comment: Crux seems to be identifying the "cheapest" range. Length of range here is 5, obviously, and with lowest and highest being 1 and 10, resp., we could use any one of 1..5 through 6..10. So see which one has the most hits, i.e. has the fewest entries that need changing.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError First length of the array is not fixed. Second maybe lowest and highest being 200 and 300.

Comment: Obviously length of array and lowest and highest value will need to be determined up front.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError So can you explain that ?

Comment: How large is the problem space? How many gaps in the sequence, how large the total range (1..10? 1..100000?), how many numbers in the list? For small ranges, the brute-force method outlined in the 'Crux' comment above suggests a simple, useful approach. But if you have 100000 numbers and thousands of gaps it would quickly lose its usefulness

Comment: "no repetition is allowed" -- does this mean input of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]` must become `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` (dup removed) or `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` (dup becomes new integer and extends range)? Or does it mean that there should never be duplicates in the input?

Comment: @Nick According to OPs description, [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5] should become a list of six not-necessarily-ordered consecutive integers.

Comment: @Nick OP already clarified that the only operation allowed is to change one integer to another integer.

Comment: גלעד ברקן thanks for the response. Please check my revised comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got some good results with the algorithm below. See also the hand-crafted example and the Python implementation [here](https://gist.github.com/nick-mellor-planittesting/af5e6a7df24c32f5ff1caafe8c24d9ae).

## Observations and Definitions

One way of summarising the task is: reduce gaps in a series of numbers to zero by renumbering as few numbers as possible.

Let's call a "run" a series of one or more consecutive integers like `[45, 46, 47]`. And a "gap" is one or more missing numbers in a list of integers.

E.g. `[1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 11]` contains:

- four runs `[1, 2]`, `[5, 6]`, `[9]` and `[11]`
- three gaps `[3, 4]`, `[7, 8]` and `[10]`

Some observations (the hand-crafted example below may help to explain these better):

1. renumbering numbers off the runs at the end and the beginning is efficient. This is because when numbers in an "outer" run get renumbered, the run may be used up and disappear. When that happens, the gap next to it disappears too.
2. Moving "outer" numbers so they fill gaps in the middle has a chance of (a) eliminating a gap at the outer edge (b) eliminating a gap in the middle (c) increasing the length of a run. For example, renumbering `[11]` to `9` removes the `[10]` gap and increases the length of the `[9]` run but in this case reduces the size of, but does not eliminate, a gap in the middle. Both removing a gap (or gaps) and increasing the length of an existing run means there are more consecutive numbers and that we're making progress
3. conversely, renumbering a number near the middle of the list is not likely to be as efficient. At best, if the number has gaps on both sides then it is 2/3 as effective as renumbering an outer number, because it can never remove an outer gap
4. each number may be renumbered more than once during the process, but all we need is one renumber from initial value to final value. This gives us an opportunity to optimise

Some of the above observations are more probabilities than certainties, but a good strategy appears to be "renumber from the outside in."

### Algorithm

1. sort the list of numbers into ascending order so you can see where the runs and gaps are
2. take the last run of consecutive numbers (e.g. `[98, 99, 100]`) or the first run of consecutive numbers (e.g. `[1, 2]`), whichever has the fewest numbers. In this case `[1, 2]` would be picked because it has only 2 elements. If the first and last runs are of the same length, choose either
3. take numbers from the last/first run and squeeze as many as possible into the gap that's nearest the middle
4. repeat from 2 until there are no more gaps
5. optimise renumbers-- see below.

[This Python implementation](https://gist.github.com/nick-mellor-planittesting/af5e6a7df24c32f5ff1caafe8c24d9ae) uses the above algorithm. There's no guarantee that its solutions are optimal but the renumber counts are reassuringly low for small cases I've looked at closely. It solves for 5000 numbers and over 1000 gaps in a few seconds (test data in source) and the minimal number of moves is subjectively about right.

```
$ python continuous.py
Original numbers: [1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10, 13, 14, 19]
19 -> 3
14 -> 4
13 -> 7
10 -> 8
(4 renumbers)
Original order with renumbers:
[1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4, 3]
Gaps in final output (check=0): 0
Sorted:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
no of integers in original: 9
```

### Hand-crafted Example

Take the numbers `[1, ..., 3, ..., 5, 6, ..., 9, 10, 11, ..., 13, ..., 19]`:

The `[7, 8]` gap is nearest the middle (3rd gap of 5); The run `[1]` (1 number) is the same size as run `[19]` (1 number) so `1` is arbitrarily chosen from the first run and renumbers as `7`. The `[7, 8]` gap is now reduced to `[8]`; because `1` has been renumbered, there is no longer a `[2]` gap either, as the sequence now starts from the number 3:

```
[1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 13, 19] -> [*x,* 3, 5, 6, *7,* 9, 10, 11, 13, 19]
```

(`x` is where the original number was before renumbering.)

The `[8]` gap is nearest the middle (2nd gap of 3); `3` peels off from the start and renumbers as `8`, removing the `[8]` gap and the `[4]` gap:

```
[3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 19] -> [*x,* 5, 6, 7, *8,* 9, 10, 11, 13, 19]
```

The `[12]` gap is nearest the middle-- or as near the middle as the `[14..18]` gap; `[19]` is shorter than `[5..7]` so the last run, `[19]` is renumbered first. The number `19` renumbers as `12`, plugging the `12` gap and removing the `[14..18]` gap:

```
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 19] -> [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, *12,* 13, *x*]
```

Because there are no more gaps, we have an unbroken sequence of numbers `[5..13]`.

The answer is how many numbers you have moved:

```
1 -> 7, 3 -> 8, 19 -> 12 (3 moves)
```

### Optimising Renumbers

What if the `[14, 15, 16, 17, 18]` gap had been chosen as the middle gap instead of the `[12]` gap? In that case we'd get two renumbers: `19 -> 14` followed by `14 -> 12`.

You can optimise the answer further by collapsing redundant renumbers if there are any. As per observation 4, no number needs changing more than once, so `19 -> 14` followed by `14 -> 12` is equivalent to `19 -> 12`. If you have two or more renumbers that are chained like this, they can be replaced by one renumber.

As a further example, the sequence `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]` could be consolidated using the following renumbers:

```
9 -> 6, 7 -> 2, 6 -> 4
```

This can be reduced to:

```
9 -> 4, 7 -> 2
```

giving the continuous run `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` in 2 moves rather than 3.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

Let `L` be the length of your array. Then you want to find first the range of numbers that will minimize your convertions `[Min,Max]`. So:

1. calculate the histogram of your array `IniArray`.
2. calculate an array with the same length as your histogram which has the value `1` where the histogram bin is filled and `0` otherwise (I will call it `Mask`). This step can be computed almost directly without having to calculate the histogram in step (1); it is calculated the same way as the histogram but instead of adding +1 to the bins, just assign them the value '1'.
3. Calculate the Mean Filter of this array using a filter size of `L`. This can be done by first computing the cummulated array (`Cummul`) of the `Mask`and then taking differences

```
 MeanFilter[i] = (Cummul[min(i+L/2,L-1)] - Cummul[max(0,i+L/2-L-1)])/L
```

4. The index (I) of the maximum value in `MeanFilter` will give you the required range.  `[Min,Max]= [min(I+L/2,L-1) , max(0,I+L/2-L-1) ]`. If the maximum value is repeated take any of their corresponding indexes.
5. Let `S`be the summatory of the values of `Mask` within the range `[Min,Max]`, then the minimum number of operations`N` is calculated as `N=L-S`

If the order doesn't matter, then the final array is just the sequence of integers from Min to Max. If you need the precise convertion operations and you want to maintain the initial array order as much as possible:

6. Create an array (`Filled`) of length 'L' and initialize all its values to a value outside the range `[Min,Max]`. This value `NFV` will be the reference value meaning "not yet filled".
7. for each element `V` in your initial array, calculate its index position in the histogram as `J=V-Min`. If `J<0` or `J>=L`, do nothing for the moment. Otherwise, if `Filled[J]==NFV`, then set `Filled[J]=V`;  else do nothing.
8. We repeat step 7 but this time we will store the changes: for each element `IniArray[i]=V` in your initial array, calculate its index position in the histogram as `J=V-Min`. If `J<0` or `J>=L` or `Filled[J]!=NFV`, iterate throughout `Filled` until you find `Filled[K]==NFV` and then note down the change **(IniArray[i]=V) => (K+Min)** and update 'Filled[K]==K+Min`

Comment: Tnx for the solution. But your solution is too complicated.

Comment: Actually, if you only need the number of changes (steps 1 to 5) it is very simple .

Answer (score 1):

Let A[0..N) be the sorted array. Two consecutive elements A[i-1] and A[i] have a gap if A[i-1] + 1 < A[i] (the size of the gap is A[i] - A[i-1] - 1 max 0).

A trivial but important observation is that in a minimal solution the elements that are converted belong to the left and/or right hand sides of the array.

More precisely, any minimal solution can be characterized as a partition A[0..L) A[L..N-R) A[N-R..N), for some L and R (0 ≤ L ≤ N-R ≤ N), where all the elements of A[0..L) and A[N-R..N) will be converted. No element of A[L..N-R) gets converted and any gaps it may contain are (afterwards) filled using the results of the left- and right hand side conversions (L+R in total) .

Define G(L,R) be the total size of the gaps in A[L..N-R), i.e. G(L,R) = (Σi: L < i < N-R : A[i] - A[i-1] - 1 max 0). Then (L,R) is a solution (not necessarily a minimal one) if G(L,R) ≤ L+R (since then there are enough converted numbers to fill all the gaps in A[L..N-R)). Furthermore, (L,R) is a minimal solution if L+R is minimal.

Hence the essence of the problem is to minimize L+R such that G(L,R) ≤ L+R.

G (or rather G(L,R)-L-R) is decreasing in both arguments, so this minimization problem can easily be solved in O(N) time & space.

Addendum: after rereading the question I noticed that duplicates are undesirable, so the minimization problem is not G(L,R) ≤ L+R, but rather G(L,R) ≤ L+R + D(L,R), where D(L,R) = the number of duplicates in [L..N-R). It hardly matters for the algorithm, but it does affect some of the wording above (since the remaining D(L,R) duplicates in the middle part do undergo conversion). An easier but less intuitive alternative is to define the gap size as as abs(A[i]-A[i-1]-1).

Comment: If the solution you are applying is on a sorted array, given that the input is not ordered, the sorting would make overall complexity O(n log n). Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: That's right. The minimization problem is O(N) (typically solved using dynamic programming). The preprocessing part is sorting and would take O(N log N) in general (if the integers can take any value). So the overall complexity is O(N log N)

(Perhaps I should have written "Let A[0..N) be the array, after sorting it" to avoid confusion)

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this with `O(n log n)` complexity by sorting the array, collapsing any duplicates into a single entry -- call this `B`. Then for each entry in `B` as a candidate for the lowest value, `low`, in the solution; we fix the highest value, `high` as `low + input_length - 1`. The cost for each such candidate is now the input length subtracted by the number of elements in `B` that are in the `[low, high]` range, which can be found in `O(n)` for the entire iteration by augmenting a pointer to the index for `high` as we iterate. (We might need to mirror for each candidate as the potential `high` as well.) Pick the lowest cost.

For example:

```
Input: 6 4 1 7 10

B:     1 4 6 7 10

Candidates:

[1, 5]  cost 5 - 2 = 3
[4, 8]  cost 5 - 3 = 2
[6, 10] cost 5 - 3 = 2
[7, 11] cost 5 - 2 = 3
...etc


Input: 1 4 4 4 4

B: 1 4

Candidates:

[1, 5] cost 5 - 2 = 3
...etc
```

Comment: I'm not sure collapsing duplicates is allowed. You may need to swap them with another number. Waiting for clarification in OP

Comment: @Nick collapsing duplicates is part of my algorithm. There's no question about whether it is allowed or not. It's not related to the input.

Comment: There is an ambiguity in OP. Example of the problem in OP comments. Nothing wrong with your algo but it might need to be altered depending on what "no repetition is allowed" actually means. Does it mean "duplicates not allowed in input" or "duplicates not allowed in output"?

Comment: @גלעדברקן for each of candidates say [1,5] we need to find the elements between this range in the array B which also takes a O(n) time so your algo time complexity will became a O(nlogn) +O(n^2) which is not efficient. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: RajatKashyap the overall complexity of the algorithm in my answer is O(n log n) due to sorting the input. The rest is O(n).